# Extracting curved line features

Tags: algorithm, math

I have a curved line in a matrix and i need to calculate below cases :

1. Radius of curvature top
2. Curve is upside or downside
3. Length of line

For example in below image i need to know above cases about green line(i have green line data, no need to image processing) :

[image: Below image]

Comment: How your lines are defined?

Comment: Line is drawn by user on device screen, consider it as a 2D matrix with 0 and 1 values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have a set of points and need to describe continuous lines mathematically
(get some approximation).

For example, you can build polynomial approximation over points at the line border (seems you lines have thickness) with least squares method (use rather low polynom power).

Having polynom, you can estimate if it is convex upward or downward through the second derivative - note that high-power polynoms might have different convexity sign at distinct segments.

Having two polynoms for "low" and "upper" borders, you can calculate their difference and get area between them with integration.

To get length, you need to integrate along the curve.

Comment: Thanks for your great response @Mbo, but i think i did ask my question in bad way about case 1, for case 1i need to have a standard to measure line curve amount.
For example straight line curve amount is 0.
Can we measure it based on degree?

Comment: Emm... Curvature? What to do with line 4? - it definitely changes curvature.

Comment: Yes exactly curvature, 
about line 4 i think i should have a threshold about curvature, and we will consider just top of line 4.

Comment: i found a formula to calculate radius of curvature of polynomial :
https://www.intmath.com/applications-differentiation/8-radius-curvature.php

Comment: Yes, this is appropriate formula for case when you define curve for as `y=f(x)` . Note that you need curvature as inverse of radius 1/R to get 0 for straight line and larger values for bended curves

Comment: Thanks MBo but just radius and your suggestion solved my problem.